# Warning C4267 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting the below warning message when compiling my C++ application,

**Warning   C4267   'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data
at the below line:**

```
DWORD nPos = strRegPath.find(REG_SOFTWARE);
```

**Below is my complete code:**

**Declaration:**

```
#define REG_SOFTWARE L"Software"
wchar_t* m_wszParams;
```

**Definition:**

```
wstring strRegPath = m_wszParams;

DWORD nPos = strRegPath.find(REG_SOFTWARE);
```

Could anyone please help me how to resolve this warning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DWORD` in MSWindows is of type 32 bit unisgned. `size_t` in any 64 bits OS is a 64 bit unsigned. So casting 64bit to 32bit may loss data.

Comment: Unless your string length exceeds a 32 bit unsigned (meaning 2GB) it won't cause you a problem however why do you want this to be a `DWORD`?

Comment: `auto` is fine to have real type. (even if later, you might need the conversion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `DWORD` falling behind `std::size_t` in terms of size. If writing

```
std::size_t nPos = strRegPath.find(REG_SOFTWARE);
```

merely kicks the can down the road, that is you get a warning elsewhere, then you can either force the issue with

```
static_cast<DWORD>(strRegPath.find(REG_SOFTWARE));
```

whereupon you're essentially telling the compiler you know what you're doing which ought to be sufficient to suppress the warning, or use something that makes a run-time check to verify you're not losing data: a `numeric_cast` from Boost can help there:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html

Comment: Hi @Bathsheba, without using static_cast, can I cast it like as shown below:

Comment: (DWORD)(strRegPath.find(REG_SOFTWARE));

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder: Sure, you can "C-style cast" it, but the `static_cast` is clearer.